# Как правильно описать бизнес процесс (ddd)?

Tags: java, архитектура, проектирование, ddd

Есть бизнес, в котором пользователь, зарегистрировавшись (используя почту и пароль) может получить консультацию специалиста в неком чате.

После этого он может придти (а может не придти) уже ногами в офисы и заключить договор (который уже включает другие данные - паспортные и т.д.).
Пользователь может так же просто сразу придти в офис и заключить договор.

Как разделить это всё?

```
User(Email email, Email password) can go to Office (Email email, Email password, Passport: passport) and Get() any Services()
```

Пользователь - это Entity, ok.

У него есть идентификатор, его можно зарегистрировать и прочее. А вот когда он приходит в офис, чтобы заключить договор - это еще одна сущность Client() или нет? Или это тот же User просто без "паспортной" части? И где должна находится валидация этого? в Email, Name, Passport как в Value-Object или, если это разные сущности, должен быть какой то сервис выделен, к которому я обращаюсь из Value object?

Answer (score 2):

Например, можно ввести роли. Если человек только зарегистрировался то Role.USER, дошел до офиса, то уже Role.CLIENT, логично было бы работать с одной Entity и все поля в ней держать

Comment: если держать всё в одном поле, это это во первых избыточная информация, второе много блоков `IF` для проверки, `кто это`

Answer (score 1):

То что вы описали, мы разделили логику на следующие сущности.
Заинтересованный пользователь, это `Leed (Лид)` который интересуется услугами компаниями.
После его регистрации, данный `Лид` может конвертироваться уже в другую сущность, например в `Client`.

Таким образом, у нас в базе нет избыточной информации плюс в коде нет множества блоков `IF` для определения кто это, клиент с полными данными, или же лид

Comment: Спасибо. А как вы конвертите их? Как то идентификаторы сущностей сохраняются в одном месте? У меня по идее, и Лид, который стал клиентом, может продолжать пользоваться сервисом не приходя в офис.

Comment: Дополнительная таблица для связки `лида-с-клиентом`. Вам просто нужно для начала определить что есть Лид. Допустим он дал свой `Email` - ок, это Лид. Получили больше информации (паспортные данные или же еще что-то) - создали уже Клиента, связали его с Лидом, что бы история была целой.